# Using strtok, last token comes with a line delimiter

Tags: c, strtok

So when writing this code and showing the last token it comes with the line delimiter "\n", how do i take that out?

```
 while( fgets( c, MAX_viagens, f) != NULL ) {
    int i = 0;
    char *p = strtok (c, ":");
    char *array[6];

        while (p != NULL){
         array[i++] = p;
         p = strtok (NULL, ":");
        }
    printf ("%s\n", array[3]);
```

Comment: probably best to strip the newline after `fgets` and before `strtok`.  Like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28462221/10396)

Comment: @AShelly that's actually the cleanest solution, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One simple way to achieve this is to add the new line character to the delimiters:

```
char *p = strtok (c, ":\n");
...
p = strtok (NULL, ":\n");
```

Or you could remove it before (removes last character, even if it is not `'\n'`):

```
if(c[0])
{
    c[strlen(c)-1] = '\0';
}
```

Comment: I think your first example is the way to go. But, `strlen` has an extra cost, so, for your second example, I'd do: `int len = strlen(c); if (len) c[len - 1] = 0;`

Comment: @CraigEstey Yes it would be more efficient to call `strlen` only one time. But if you enable optimization I think the compiler should recognize it.

Comment: @CraigEstey I changed it to a simpler check.

Comment: I think that's a good idea. Because this: `#include <string.h>  char *c; void funny(char *ptr);  int main(void) {  for (int idx = 0;  idx < strlen(c);  ++idx) funny(&c[idx]);  return 0; }` _doesn't_ optimize the `strlen` to a single call. Because it _can't--it has to assume `funny` can change the string and `strlen` will return a different value. Helping the compiler [rather than _relying_ on it] is good practice, IMO.